# Z score from confidence level

Tags: self-study, z-test

I'm trying to find the Z score from a confidence level, for a Z test. I found posts with questions pretty close to this, but I'm still not sure of the general solution.

These are the data I have:
A car battery manufacturer has a 5 year warranty. The engineer supposes the battery will break before 5 years. At 2% significance level, should the warranty be revised?

n = 40 (sample size)

sample_mean = 4.8

sample_std = 0.5

hypothesis mean = 5

alpha = 0.02

I write $H_0$ = hypothesis_mean = 5

Then $H_a$ = sample_mean < hypothesis mean (the battery will break before 5 years).

Since $H_a$_mean < $H_0$_mean then it's, left tail test (one side).

You don't do the $Z$ test without population std, but since n is large (> 30) we can assume it is enough.

I know that to find the $Z$ score you need to calculate the area under the curve.

Usually to find it you can do $AL = \frac{(1+CL)}{2}$ with CL in this case being 0.98 ($CL = 1-\alpha$).

And here's my problem: The AL formula works when you have 2 tails, since you need to divide the area by 2. But if you have just 1 tail, what is the right action? Calculate the $Z$ score from the confidence level alone?

By applying the above AL formula I find AL=0.99 and that gives a Z score of -2.33
But if I just calculate the Z score with AL $= 0.98$ (CL) then Z score $= -2.06$

Which solution is correct? And what is the general rule?

Comment: What is the criterion for re-writing the warranty? Is this an alternate reality in which battery lifetimes are normally distributed? This seems a strange use for a CI. However, an upper 98% confidence bound based on dist'n $\mathsf{T}(\nu=39)$ is $4.9680$ (from Minitab). A z interval is a poor approximation here.

Comment: I took the exercis from here [link](https://youtu.be/8Aw45HN5lnA?t=725). As you can see he uses the p-value for solving the problem, but I can't see why we can't use the z interval here?  
Even if this isn't a good case for z interval approximation, I'm trying to understand how to find the Z score from a one side tail case given a confidence level.

Comment: Viewing a CI as a probability statement is controversial, Suggest you try to understand the approach using a P-value..